# JavaScript validación de formulario no hace nada

Tags: javascript, validación

Buen día, tengo una validación de un formulario, pero el javascript no hace nada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarFormulario(){


        var txtIdentificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
        if(!isNaN(txtIdentificacion)) {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }
         if(txtIdentificacion == " ") {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }



    }
    </script>

<form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post" onsubmit='return validarFormulario()'>
<div>
    <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil:  </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil"/>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Guardar</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


    <button type="button">Limpiar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos te comento lo siguiente

1. Tu código JS debe ir al final del documento por 2 razones primero si lo pones arriba en ese punto aún no conoce las etiquetas que estas intentando manipular, alenta la visualización del archivo
2. Tienes declarada la función pero no la estas mandando llamar en ningún lado, aprovechando los eventos con JS la mando llamar en el botón de guardar en el evento onclick, por cierto le quite la propiedad submit para evitar5 se recargue
3. No es necesario que niegues el método isNaN ya que por defecto este método niega que un valor que recibe es numérico
4. En tu segunda validación, no le veo sentido a tu mensaje pues ya arriba pides que sea numero, ademas que tiene espacio en blanco en medio de las comillas; en todo caso deben ser comillas sin espacio en medio para indicar que ese campo no debe quedar en blanco, checa como lo deje

Mira como lo he dejado

```
<form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil:  </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil"/>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="button" onclick="validarFormulario()" name="submit" >Guardar</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


    <button type="button">Limpiar</button>
</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validarFormulario(){


        var txtIdentificacion = document.getElementById('identificacion').value;
        if(isNaN(txtIdentificacion)) {
            alert ("Identificación debe ser un número");
            return false;
        }
         if(txtIdentificacion == "") {
        alert ("Identificación no puede quedar en blanco");
        return false;
        }



    }
    </script>
```

> Como observación final quita el submit de la etiqueta form y mejor
>   manejalo como te indico con el evento onclick desde el botón de
>   guardar, además que como te indico cuando usas submit el comportamiento por > defecto es recargar la página

---

> También te comento no es necesario que en la etiqueta de script
>   coloques esto **type="text/javascript"**, por defecto el navegador
>   sabe que es código JavaScript

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste Alfredo.. ahora funciona, gracias